# Combine Multiple Queries different Where Clause

Tags: sql

I have 2 queries that I would like to combine into one.  Basically I want the 2 queries to be in one output table... output would look like this…

```
 
Store        GC Sold             Total Cars

1               22                    75

2                24                    88

3                15                    89
```

The problem is I can’t figure out how to get it in the same table.

Here are my queries…

```
SELECT        Store_Number, COUNT_BIG(Quantity_Sold) AS GC Sold
FROM            Invoice_Detail_Tb
WHERE        (Invoice_Date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @startdate, 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, @enddate, 102)) AND (JLI_Category_Code = 'gc') 
                         AND (Invoice_Detail_Code LIKE 'jlgc%') AND (Invoice_Detail_Type = 'Item')
GROUP BY Store_Number
```

This Output is:

```
Store Number      GC Sold

1                    12

2                    13

3                    14
```

```
SELECT   Store_Number,
         SUM(Vehicle_Count) AS [Total_Cars]
FROM     Daily_Sales_Tb
WHERE    (Operations_Day BETWEEN CONVERT (DATETIME, @startdate, 102) AND CONVERT (DATETIME, @enddate, 102))
GROUP BY Store_Number;
```

Output:

```
Store Number       Total Cars

1                      7

2                      8

3                      9
```

Separately, the queries work as designed. However if I try to combine them they are 2 different aggregate functions so it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT A.Store_Number,A.GC_Sold,B.Total_Cars
FROM
(
SELECT        Store_Number, COUNT_BIG(Quantity_Sold) AS GC_Sold
FROM            Invoice_Detail_Tb
WHERE        (Invoice_Date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @startdate, 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, @enddate, 102)) AND (JLI_Category_Code = 'gc') 
                         AND (Invoice_Detail_Code LIKE 'jlgc%') AND (Invoice_Detail_Type = 'Item')
GROUP BY Store_Number
) A,
(
SELECT   Store_Number,
         SUM(Vehicle_Count) AS [Total_Cars]
FROM     Daily_Sales_Tb
WHERE    (Operations_Day BETWEEN CONVERT (DATETIME, @startdate, 102) AND CONVERT (DATETIME, @enddate, 102))
GROUP BY Store_Number
) B
WHERE A.Store_Number=B.Store_Number;
```

Comment: I can't vote up... I don't have enough reputations, but I accepted the answer.  Thanks again.

Comment: What if I wanted to drop a second output with the above query?  Like lets say I wanted 1 output as above, but then My next output i wanted for JUST @enddate... How would I accomplish that in 1 query?